# problems accessing refresh / access CSRF cookies on different paths

Tags: security, web, cookies

I have a backend that is setting two JWT tokens (access and refresh, httpOnly and secure), and providing two CSRF cookies (access and refresh, secure). For any normal request I need to provide the JWT access cookie and the content of the CSRF access cookie as a header, and to refresh the JWT access I need to provide the JWT refresh cookie and the CSRF refresh cookie as a header.

In my requests I handle the expiration of the access token programmatically: I do the request using the access cookie and header, and in case I get an unauthorized I point a request to the refresh endpoint with the refresh cookie and header, and done.

This is something I can implement for an app, programmatically, but I am facing trouble doing the same with the browser, because from a random page in the domain I cannot access a cookie that is for another document  (so, if the refresh cookies are set for the path /api/refresh, I cannot generate a request to that from the current url /api/another that contains the cookie for /api/refresh).

Can my problem only be solved by setting the path for refresh and access cookies to '/'? Doesn't this introduce a problem, by sending the refresh cookie every time with my requests?